# PHP Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed

Tags: php, html

Hello I'm using an old script and I am getting this error when trying to 
access the site thats the script is running on.

```
Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /home/image/public_html/*****/admin/inc/html.inc.php on line 86
```

Here is the Php code from line 83 down to 89 I'm running Php version 5.5.20

```
if ($flag) {
    $out  = '';
    $find = '{CONSTVAR:$';
    html_replacevar(&$html, $find, $page);
    if (strpos($html, '{') === FALSE) {
        $out = $html;
    }
```

Can anyone that knows php tell what might be the problem im having,and how to fix it? I'm new to php and coding so thats why I need help. Thank you very much.

Comment: change   html_replacevar(&$html, $find, $page); to   html_replacevar($html, $find, $page);

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu see comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38551028/315024)

Comment: Going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are passing variable by reference. As the error says. Try to modify the function `html_replacevar` in such a way that it will return the modified html and use it like this:

```
$html = html_replacevar($html, $find, $page);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is about understanding references. A function parameter that is a reference passes that actual variable, so modifications to it inside the function will persist outside of the function. The default is for variables passed to a function to be copies, so changing it inside the function has no effect outside the function. The exception to this rule is parameters that are objects, whereby changes to them (not reassignment of the variable) always persist.

References are variables preceded by an `&`. You used to be able to choose whether to use references at call-time, you could do either of these:

```
$foo = bar($baz);
$foo = bar(&$baz);
```

Only the second would mean `bar()` could return a value *and* make changes to the original `$baz`. Now, to make the language clearer and more efficient, you can only set which parameters are references in a function's/method's signature, e.g.:

```
function bar(&$qux) {
    …
}
```

Now everyone knows that function intends to modify its first parameter, and you never add the `&` to a referenced parameter in the call.

Answer (score 0):

PHP no longer allows pass-by-reference on function calls, however it does allow this in function definitions.

Try replacing

```
html_replacevar(&$html, $find, $page);
```

with

```
html_replacevar($html, $find, $page);
```

Comment: Their function does not seem to return a value, so your solution may get rid of the error but also suppress the intended effect on `$html`.